# Problem between opticals and minionint options in the MinionPro package

Tags: math-mode, fonts, errors, bold, minionpro

I've already told the author of the `MinionPro` package about this. But I post it here to see if somebody solves it before him:

This document:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[minionint,opticals]{MinionPro}

\begin{document}
\boldmath $a+b$
\end{document}
```

does not compile.

This is the error I get:

> ! I can't find file `MnSymbolFI-Bold10'.
>
> ! Emergency stop.

Why? Is it a “code only” problem and therefore can be solved here easily? Or it's a problem of the font itself and then I should wait to an official solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has been now fixed in [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro/) in [this commit](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro/commit/e063a9027f640423d0c7969ab583d1f952773193). The original authors of the [MinionPro project](http://developer.berlios.de/projects/minionpro/) [deliberately disabled](http://cvs.berlios.de/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/minionpro/MinionPro/fontinst/make-MnSymbolFI.tex?r1=1.10&r2=1.11) the specific combination of bold font and opticals for the generation of integral signs derived from the MinionPro font. I do not see why this would make sense so the change has now been reverted. Please test and comment if necessary.

Comment: That was fast. It's done. This is not a question at this moment. Anyway, thank you.